# Can I carry a removed from service Cessna 182 propeller from the US to Russia?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, luggage, souvenirs, export-certificate

I want to bring a gift to my buddy in Russia, and he's very much into aviation, so I found a defective aluminum Cessna propeller for him.
It fits the luggage and the airline accepts it, but I'm worried if I can export it from the US. It's going to have a tag from tech inspection that it cannot be used on a certified aircraft due to some wear on a blade. 
Local FAA office doesn't take phone calls, probably due to the government shutdown.
How is this regulated? Can I carry out it as a souvenir?

I have read in several places that high tech US production such as aircraft, engines, propellers and their blades are subject to export regulation, but the only definite thing I found so far is airworthiness certification of the FAA.

---

EDIT:
My concerns are because of this:
https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/international/export_aw_approval/export_aw_process/
and this:
https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/international/export_aw_approval/media/8130-3QA.pdf

---

EDIT 2:
CBP is able to answer this question, they have an item in their help phone line's automated menu about goods that are possible to be under export regulations, but they aren't working these days.
https://www.cbp.gov/contact

Comment: Why do you think this might be a problem?

Comment: It wouldn't be FAA for export control, it would likely be the Bureau of Industry and Security of the Department of Commerce (the other being Office of Defense Trade Controls in the State Department for military-related controls). Unfortunately, both are closed at the moment.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I edited my post adding docs because of which I have my concerns.

Comment: @user71659 Can you give more context? What docs I could refer to? Thanks

Comment: @user71659 wouldn't CBP have the job of enforcing any such export controls?  Would they be able to help determine whether the propeller in question is affected?  They at least are working during the shutdown.

Comment: Why is the airworthiness of a decommissioned propeller even relevant? It's decommissioned. You don't need to show it's airworthy. It's just a big funny shaped object.

Comment: @MichaelHampton True, I just want to oversee any problems and not to miss my flight because of the customs officers questions, because the export of such things is regulated. It might be some other organization responsible for the permission of export...

Comment: I can't imagine any reason why customs would care in the least about you exporting it. You should seriously be concerned about how much the airline is going to charge you for carrying it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's gonna be within their luggage restrictions, so it's covered by the ticket :) I checked that with them

Comment: @MichaelHampton Aerospace components are often subject to export controls. The penalties are severe and include fines and jail. You should not assume that you are allowed to bring it out of the country.

Comment: @phoog you were right, CBP is able to answer my question, but they aren't working. They have an entry about questions about exports of specific goods that might be subject to regulations in their phone automated menu, but it's turned off. Thank you for the hint anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton "Decomissioned" just means that its owner took it off a plane and doesn't intend putting it back on one. The fact that it's decomissioned doesn't tell you anything about its possible aerospace applications.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The exact thing is that it is kind of defective, and was removed from service because it cannot be used on a certified aircraft. Maybe "decommissioned" is the wrong choice of words.

Comment: @Battle_Slug CBP *is* working, since people and goods continue to enter and leave the US, but I am not surprised that some parts of CBP are closed.  You ought to be able to talk to someone at your nearest international airport.

Comment: Are you sure he isn't a spy? If the Russians reverse-engineer that Cessna propellor and suddenly there are deadly silent [Tu-95 bombers](https://foxtrotalpha.jalopnik.com/this-is-what-its-like-inside-the-loudest-plane-in-the-w-1822666940) flying around, *it's all your fault*. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it will be a problem. Reading through the [Form 8130 FAQ](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/air_cert/international/export_aw_approval/media/8130-3QA.pdf), it's pretty clear that the FAA wants all parts **to be used on a flying aircraft** to have that form. Remember, the title of Form 8130 is (emphasis mine)

> Export **Airworthiness** Approval

The propeller has already been deemed unworthy of future use as a propeller. If CBP questions you about it, tell the truth and say you bought it as a gift for decorating a friend's house. Since it has a tag deeming it unworthy for flight, they'll probably consider it junk.

Comment: That's also my thought. I just don't want to be caught for "trying to smuggle". All my explanations wouldn't mean anything if they decided that it should have been declared somehow and it wasn't. And that part is not clear.

Comment: @Battle_Slug But you're not trying to smuggle it, you're just trying to clear CBP. If you're up front and honest there shouldn't be an issue. We're not talking new parts here. I seriously doubt most CBP agents would even know about FAA export regulations

Comment: @Machavity I also doubt they'd know the details of most Department of Agriculture import restrictions. It doesn't matter: when they don't know stuff, they look it up.

Comment: Any restrictions to consider on arrival in Russia?

Comment: @Traveller I didn't find any specific to airplane parts, let alone unusable ones